# Web site for plan upload and measure

Tags: scale, web, measurements

I've got plans of my house and a warehouse on paper. I would like to scan them in JPEG, import them on my PC and measure them. 
I'm looking for a website where I can upload those tiff, jpeg or pdf files, define a scale (measuring something of known measure to give a correct scale to the entire image), measure the rooms by drawing polygons over them, and print out the images with my measured polygons or send them to my email with the total area reported.
I can't find anything like this on the web. Is this kind of utility uncommon? Can any body suggest a simple solution for measuring my planimetry without installing any software?

Comment: Please provide more context and details -- it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @martinf I've added something to my question, please send me a feedback if it is still not clear

Comment: Much clearer now (i really had no idea before)! Do we assume the plans weren't produced by CAD (or the CAD files are missing)?

Comment: @martinf yes, I only have raster files. I'm speaking about old paper designs.

Answer (score -4):

1. Set floor-plan in the background image
2. Draw polygon on the background
3. Expose the floor-plan into map
4. Ready